# How do you add an Action<string> to an interface?

Tags: c#, .net

As the question title suggests, I want to add an `Action<string>` to an interface. Is this possible? At the moment it says `Interfaces cannot contain fields`

Comment: It is bad design to add delegates to your contract/interface.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk could you explain/proof that?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You'd need to add it as a property:

```
public interface IYourInterface
{
    Action<string> YourAction { get; set; }
}
```

Without the get/set it's just a field, and as the compiler points out interfaces can't contain fields.  This does mean that when you implement this interface you'll need to supply the actual property as well (though obviously it can be a simple auto-property):

```
public class Foo : IYourInterface
{
    public Action<string> YourAction { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Given that, you can then use your `Action<string>` from the interface:

```
IYourInterface iFoo = new Foo();

iFoo.YourAction = s => Console.WriteLine(s);

iFoo.YourAction("Hello World!");
```

As Hans indicated, you can indicate in your interface just a `get` (or even just a `set`) if you want.  This doesn't mean the class *can't* have the other, it just means it won't be accessible through the interface.  For example:

```
public interface IYourInterface
{
    Action<string> YourAction { get; }
}

public class Foo : IYourInterface
{
    public Action<string> YourAction { get; set; }
}
```

So in the above code, you could access the `YourAction` property only as a `get` through the interface, but you could `set` or `get` it from the `Foo` class.

Comment: As an additional note: in an interface you can specify that there is just a "get": `Action<string> YourAction { get; }`, leaving it up to the implementation how/whether to provide a "set".

Comment: Very true.  You can even specify it just has a set (though this is somewhat less useful)

Answer (score 0):

An interface can't contain fields, but they can contain properties, so you could add it that way.

Answer (score -2):

I quote:

> "Interfaces consist of methods, properties, events, indexers, or any
>   combination of those four member types. An interface cannot contain
>   constants, fields, operators, instance constructors, destructors, or
>   types. It cannot contain static members. Interfaces members are
>   automatically public, and they cannot include any access modifiers"

since  Action is a feild - it couldn't be a part of interface.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Comment: Who says it must be a field. It could be a property as well.